# How to link to a module with different name in Haddock?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I have a module defined as `foo.bar` and I want to reference it from a different part of the project. However for legibility I want it to show up as `bar` not `foo.bar`.

Normally I would just use `"foo.bar"`, but Haddock would show `foo.bar`. Is there a way to customize the name?

Follow up: What if I want to complexly change the name of the link? Sometimes I want to reference  module from a middle of the text. I want to write something like:

```
-- | There are (other examples)[foo.bar] and ..
```

to get

> There are **other examples** and ..

where the bolded part is a link to `foo.bar`

However the best I can do right now is:

```
-- | There are other examples ("foo.bar") and ..
```

which produces

> There are other examples (foo.bar) and ..

Which is not always ideal.

Comment: It seems haddock now supports your use case https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#linking-to-modules

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid that, at the time of this writing, the answer is “no.”